# How to decode utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8, byte, decode

I get an error that I don't understand. Could any of you please help med understand what's going on? These codes work on my friends computer, but not on my computer. We use all the same import files, so it shouldn't be those.

Here are my codes:

```
from pylab import *
from vm1 import *
from vm2 import *
from vm3 import *
from vmRutemønster import *
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


#*********************  MODUL ORM   ******************
#These are the codes

#Ruter som denne snaken opptar. Siste element er hodet.
#poskol=posisjon kolonne, og posrad=posisjon rad
poskol=[] #Element nr.0 er kolonne til hale, siste er kol til hode
posrad=[] #Element nr.0 er rad til hale, siste er rad til hode
retning=""#Retning kan være "høyre", "opp", "venstre" eller "ned".
ormetegn=""#Tegnet vi skal tegne ormen med, oftest "*"

def tegnhelesnaken():
    """Tegner alle "leddene" til ormen, angitt i datastrukturen.
    Bruk ormetegn på hvert ledd. Bruk "skrivrute" fra modulen
    vmRutemønster.py """
    skrivrute()

#end tegnhelesnaken

def initsnake(kolL,radL,ormeretning,tegn):
    """Lager en snake som har ledd/stjerner angitt i listene.
    Initier posisjonslistene, retning og ormetegn. Til
    slutt tegnes hele ormen. Husk å vis reultatet."""
    global poskol,posrad,retning,ormetegn
    poskol=kolL
    posrad=radL
    for i in range(0,len(kolL)):
        skrivrute(tegn,kolL[i],radL[i])
    retning=ormeretning

#end initsnake

def finnnyhodepos():
    """Finner ny posisjon til hode ut fra gammel posisjon
    og fra retningen"""
    if retning=="høyre":
        nyhodekol=poskol[len(poskol)-1]+1
        nyhoderad=posrad[len(posrad)-1]
    elif retning=="venstre":
        nyhodekol=poskol[len(poskol)-1]-1
        nyhoderad=posrad[len(posrad)-1]
    elif retning=="opp":
        nyhoderad=posrad[len(posrad)-1]-1
        nyhodekol=poskol[len(poskol)-1]
    elif retning=="ned":
        nyhoderad=posrad[len(posrad)-1]+1
        nyhodekol=poskol[len(poskol)-1]
    return nyhodekol ,nyhoderad
#end finnnyhodepos

def fjernhalen():
    """Blanker ruta med halen og fjerner halen fra
    datastrukturen (listene) (Bruk del på elementene nr.0)"""
    if retning=="høyre":
        del poskol[0]
    elif retning=="venstre":
        del poskol[0]
    elif retning=="opp":
        del posrad[0]
    elif retning=="ned":
        del posrad[0]
#end fjernhalen    

def flytt():
    """Tegner nytt hode på riktig plass i forhold til nåværende
    hode og retning. Bruk funksjonen over. Husk å oppdatere
    datastrukturen, altså posisjonslistene.  Visk så ut
    halen med "blankrute". """
    global ormlengde
    ormlengdenaa=len(poskol)
    print("ormlengde=",ormlengde,"ormlengdenaa=",ormlengdenaa)
    #først nytt hode, bruk append
    nyhodekol,nyhoderad=finnnyhodepos()
    poskol.append(nyhodekol)
    posrad.append(nyhoderad)
    skrivrute(ormetegn,nyhodekol,nyhoderad)
    if ormlengdenaa<=ormlengde:
        fjernhalen()   
#end flytt

def snuhøyre():
    """Hvis retning er høyre så blir ny retning ned, osv.  """
    global retning
    if retning=="høyre":
        retning="ned"
    elif retning=="ned":
        retning="venstre"
    elif retning=="venstre":
        retning="opp"
    elif retning=="opp":
        retning="høyre"

#end snuhøyre

def snuvenstre():
    """Hvis retning er høyre så blir ny retning opp, osv.  """
    global retning
    if retning=="høyre":
        retning="opp"
    elif retning=="opp":
        retning="venstre"
    elif retning=="venstre":
        retning="ned"
    elif retning=="ned":
        retning="høyre"

#end snuvenstre

#***************  SLUTT MODUL ORM   ******************
#This is the test for the codes

#Her kommer et hovedprogram som tester ut noen få av funksjonene i
#modulen "vmOrm.py"

vindulengde=644;vinduhøyde=404 #Antall pixels til vinduet
flate=lagVindu(vindulengde,vinduhøyde,HVIT,"SNAKE-SPILL")#Vindu lages

initrute(20,20,BLÅ)#Setter lengde, høyde og farge på rutene
initrutemønster(vindulengde,vinduhøyde)#Finner hvor mange kolonner og rader
tegnrutemønster();show()

#Vi lager en orm som er 5 stjerner lang, hodet nederst
kolListe=[16,16,16,16,16]# Hode har rute med (kol,rad)=(16,11)
radListe=[7,8,9,10,11]# Hale har rute med (kol,rad)=(16,7)
ormlengde=len(kolListe)

initsnake(kolListe,radListe,"ned","*");show()
sovms(500)
#Så flytter vi denne ormen 7 ruter nedover
for i in range(0,7):
    flytt();show()
    sovms(100)

snuhøyre()
for i in range(0,10):
    flytt();show()
    sovms(100)

snuhøyre()
for i in range(0,10):
    flytt();show()
    sovms(200)

snuhøyre()
for i in range(0,25):
    flytt();show()
    sovms(200)

snuvenstre()
for i in range(0,5):
    flytt();show()
    sovms(200)

snuvenstre()
for i in range(0,25):
    flytt();show()
    sovms(200)
```

This is my error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Fabian Suleng/Documents/Skole/Progammering/Snake/vmOrmv1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Fabian Suleng/Documents/Skole/Progammering/Snake')
Reloaded modules: vm1, vm2, vm3
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2927, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1814, in showtraceback
    self.showsyntaxerror(filename, running_compiled_code)

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1876, in showsyntaxerror
    stb = self.SyntaxTB.structured_traceback(etype, value, elist)

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1406, in structured_traceback
    newtext = linecache.getline(value.filename, value.lineno)

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()

  File "C:\Users\Fabian Suleng\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 220: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Are your windows machines setup with different languages? It could be that the script encoding is a windows code page, not utf-8. It would be interesting to open a python shell and try to read and decode the script itself. `open('C:/Users/Fabian Suleng/Documents/Skole/Progammering/Snake/vmOrmv1.py', encoding='utf-8').read()`

Comment: `from vmRutemønster import *` looks highly suspicious as it is the first not mentioned after the "reloaded modules" in error trace. If the os filesystem is not on utf-8 you'll have trouble with the `ø`as per tdelaney comment.

Comment: The result of `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` on both systems may tell us more. Also, use a utf-8 capable editor and put `# coding=utf-8` at the top of all your scripts. With any luck your friends computer will start breaking too.

Comment: The meaning of the error: byte 0xe5 is allowed only as first byte on a sequence, which are followed by continuation bytes [one or more, according the first byte]. Such continuation bytes are in range 0x80 to 0xBF. In short: your text is not a valid UTF-8 text.